# Get the selected value of an asp dropdownlist in an asp repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater that has multiple dropdown lists and multiple buttons.
Each button is tied to the dropdown list in the repeater row. Is there a way to alert the dropdownlists value on a button click. I want the button click to alert the value of the ddl in the same repeater row.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "alert the value"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the dropdownlists selected value. You know the way there is a ddls text and its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something that relates the button to the corresponding dropdown list. You mentioned something about a *row*. But in an ASP.NET repeater there's nothing that forces you to separate rows.

But let's suppose that you have separated your rows with a `<div>`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Click me" CssClass="btn" />
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataSource="foo" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now you could subscribe to the `click` event of the button and find the corresponding dropdown:

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var ddl = $(this).closest('div').find('select');
        var selectedValue = ddl.val();
        alert(selectedValue);
        return false;
    });
});
```